# Is it Possible to have two database connection in a single page in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to that we can use both mysqli and mysql connection in a single page?
I need your suggestions

Comment: Please be more specific. We can't understand your problem if you don't say what you want to do and put the code with what you have done.

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two different database handles.

As a general rule mixing MySQL and MySQLi  in the same code is a bad idea and the MySQL code will probably get deprecated in a few years.

Comment: `mysql` is [already deprecated as of PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it' is possible with no special action required from the programmer.
However, such intermixing should be avoided as much as possible.